# How to find jump lists window?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, aero, taskbar

How to get Windows 7 jump list window via `::FindWindow` or `::EnumWindows`?

What's it's class or parent?

I can't Spy++ it because it disappears if loses focus.

Thank you.

[image: Jump list]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511446.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open spy++, open jump list, click the refresh button on spy++.

[image: Jump list]

Comment: This only works if you already know what to look for :) Spy's Find Window tool removes focus from the Jump List and it closes. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, find window searches in the currently stored list, so you need to refresh it anyway, and as long as you do that while jump window is still shown, you will be able to search for it.

Comment: Wouldn't refresh also require focus on the Spy window?

Comment: Yes but it refreshes before jump list is destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way, similar to the Spy++ technique, to find it through code as soon as it's shown using an event hook:

```
void CALLBACK WinEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK, DWORD, HWND hwnd, LONG, LONG, DWORD, DWORD) {
    std::wstring className(256, L'\0');
    std::wstring windowText;

    windowText.resize(GetWindowTextLengthW(hwnd) + 1);
    GetWindowTextW(hwnd, &windowText[0], windowText.size());
    windowText = windowText.c_str();

    GetClassNameW(hwnd, &className[0], className.size());
    className = className.c_str();

    std::wcout << "Class: \"" << className << "\"\n";
    std::wcout << "Window: \"" << windowText << "\"\n";
}

int main() {
    HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW, EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW, 
        nullptr, WinEventProc, 
        0, 0, 
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS
    );

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (hWinEventHook) {
        UnhookWinEvent(hWinEventHook);
    }
}
```

As each window is shown, it appears in the console (or whatever stdout is at the time) output as a class name of `DV2ControlHost` and text of `Jump List`. If you want to interact with it, however, I believe there's a much more structured API, though I might be mistaken.